# CodeceptJS/Puppeteer only sees elements during paused sessions

Tags: reactjs, puppeteer, codeceptjs

I'm having a very frustrating problem with testing a React app using CodeceptJS and puppeteer - it only finds elements with a custom locator only when in paused mode.

My custom locator is `data-test-id`. I'm targeting elements using `I.seeElement("$id-of-element-here")` and `I.seeNumberOfElements("$test-id", X)`.

This works *perfectly* when my tests are paused and I'm manually moving onto each step of the test, but *does not* work when the tests are executing from start to finish - targeted elements are simply not found.

Sometimes I can counter this with `I.wait(X)` or `I.refreshPage()` but I'm now running into a case where none of this helps.

I do see the `data-test-id` attributes in the HTML using both Chrome's and Chromium's dev tools. There are no typos either.

There's not much point in showing examples of targeted elements, as the problem seems to happen at random, I haven't been able to see any pattern of where/when this happens.

These are the settings of the custom locator plugin, in `codecept.conf.js`:

```
plugins{
  ...
  customLocator: {
    enabled: true,
    attribute: 'data-test-id',
  },
  ...
}
```

Any help will be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

May `waitForNavigation` is a way to go?

https://codecept.io/helpers/Puppeteer/#configuration
https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagewaitfornavigationoptions

Comment: hey, thanks for the tip! I haven't used `waitFroNavigation` yet but it looks like a good way to mitigate the problem. I'll give it a try next time I have this problem.

In this particular case though, I found my answer - the problem was I was looking for an element within a `within` block. I know - noobs, right? :)

Answer (score 0):

### Solution:

I was running the assertions in question in a rather big `within` block ([link](https://codecept.io/puppeteer/#within)), so I was ending up looking for something within an element that was no longer on the page.

It *appears* that during a `pause()`, you can find and operate on elements that are visible *at the moment* and the `within` blocks don't matter.

That's the only way I can explain why, in this situation, an element can be detected during a pause but not during the actual execution of the test from start to finish.

As soon as I moved the assertions out of the `within` block, everything was normal and behaved as expected.

Apologies for the confusion - learning every day... :)